# Trying to figure out why my radio buttons are undefined in my form

Tags: jquery, html, forms, validation

I'm working on this form, and I'm working on a way to validate it with my own code. I'm pretty sure I have an idea that will work, but I'm having trouble getting the value for my radio buttons. I know they have value, because I set up an alert every time one is clicked to say what it's value is, and whether or not it "is checked". But when my form validator tries to catch the radio values, they keep coming back as undefined. what?

Here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pg9mL4ab/1/), all my code is there. I'll only include snippets below.

**jQuery for alerting radio clicks:**

```
$(":radio").click(function(){
                alert($(this).val() + " - " + $(this).is(":checked"));  
            });
```

What I get as a result:

[image][image]

**jquery for alerting the form values:**

```
$("#invalid").click(function(){
                alert (
                    "BreederName: " + bName.val() + " - " + bName.hasClass("i-invalid") + 
                    "\nYearStart: " + year.val() + " - " + year.hasClass("i-invalid") + 
                    "\nKennelName: " + kName.val() + " - " + kName.hasClass("i-invalid") + 
                    "\nWebsite: " + website.val() + " - " + website.hasClass("i-invalid") + 
                    "\nCredit: " + credit.val() + 
                    "\nExercise: " + exercise.val());   
            });
```

When the fields are empty, or have invalid entries, my code adds a class of i-invalid, which I'm checking with this alert. Which looks something like this:

[image]

Clearly my web address validator isn't working, but I'll worry about that later. Clearly I'm not targeting my radio buttons properly, but I've used all the different ways I can think to target these two fields, and I keep coming up as undefined. Can someone help me figure out where I'm going wrong?

**HTML form fields (examples)**

```
    <!--Radio buttons for credit field-->
    <td colspan="2"><h3>Would you like your contribution acknowledged?</h3></br></br>
<input type="radio" name="credit" value="yes" width="20">
Yes, I'd like my name listed on the Contributor's page. </br>
<input type="radio" name="credit" value="no" width="20">
No, I'd rather contribute anonymously.

<!--Sample Radio buttons for exercise field, there are 10 of them -->
<input type="radio" name="exercise" value="5" width="20">5
<input type="radio" name="exercise" value="6" width="20">6</br>
```

**jQuery variable for radio fields**

```
credit = $(":radio[name=credit]:checked");
exercise = $(":radio[name=exercise]:checked");

// also tried . . .

    credit = $("input radio[name=credit]:checked");
    exercise = $("input radio[name=exercise]:checked");

    credit = $("input[name=credit]:checked");
    exercise = $("input[name=exercise]:checked");

credit = $("form radio[name='credit']:checked"); <!-- put the field name in single quotes-->
exercise = $("form radio[name='exercise']:checked");
```

Comment: had you tried adding checked to one of your radios?

Comment: Sorry you can detect invalid raidos with  if (  $("input[name=exercise]:checked").length > 0){ // one is check} else { //none checked}

Answer (score 1):

what you're doing is setting your global variables `credit` and `exercise` in the `document.ready` event. so when your **DOM** loads the values of the radio buttons are ***null*** since nothing is checked at that time.

what you need to do is set the values of the global variables inside the radio button `click` event. this way they will always be updated when a radio button is clicked.

see this code below.

```
$(":radio").click(function() {
    credit = $(":radio[name=credit]:checked");
    exercise = $(":radio[name=exercise]:checked");
    console.log($(this).val() + " - " + $(this).is(":checked"));
});
```

Here's a working **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pg9mL4ab/2/)**. hope this helps.

***EDIT:*** I've replaced `alert` with `console.log`. please check the console for ouput.

Comment: I got excited when I read this, because it makes some kind of sense. But I didn't notice the jsFiddle you posted working, and when I tried it on my own computer, it didn't work because my code now doesn't recognize the variables if I try to use them inside other functions. The error log says it can't find the variable credit or exercise. That's why I defined the variables where I did, so I could call them inside other functions. Any other ideas?

Comment: I figured it out. Since the variable had to be defined within the $("input") function that I was running, I decided to place all my validation functions, including these variables, inside the $("input") function. Now my radio variables are defined and my submit button comes to life when everything is filled out! Thanks for the tip!

Comment: you're most welcome @ShirleyDodson. please upvote and mark it as an answer if it helped you.